# The .NET Framework and .NET Standard Conflict (Compatibility Issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-framework-version

My DLL is created using the .NET Standard 1.6 and ASP.net is using .NET Framework 4+

This is the Error that I am getting

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Project targets '.NETStandard,Version=v1.6'. It cannot be
>   referenced by a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.   WebApplication

Is there a work around for this ? Using the old ASP.NET framework instead of the new ASP.NET Core
I am not a fan of the Razor syntax, however I would like to use the old aspx syntax to create web forms.

Using : VS - 2017

Answer (score 2):

Only .Net Framework 4.6.1 with tooling 2.0 supports .Net Standard 1.6. You will not be able to use DLL targeting .Net Standard 1.6 in application that's targeting .Net Full framework 4+ except 4.6.1 with tooling 2.0. Please refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) for more details on platform support and compatibility.

Comment: tried changing the framework version to 4.6.1 and .2 also for .NET Standard 1.6, However there seemed to be a compatibility issue the debugger gave me the same error. @realbart link gives me clearer picture though

Answer (score 0):

It's like referencing a 4.5 assembly from a 4.0 project:

To see what .net standard version is implemented by what version of the .net framework, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

Comment: 4.6.1 seems to be not working with 1.6 so I have to downgrade it to 1.4, also that I have received a notification on a new update which i guess is Standard 2.0 that might ease out things