# .NET Standard 2.0 Data.OleDb

Tags: .net, vb.net, oledb, .net-standard, sqlclient

In the image  below it is possible to see two projects (Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.6):

[image]

-GeneralFunctions is a .NET Standard 2.0

-TestFramework is a .NET Framework 4.6.1

My idea is to develop some functions in the .NET Std project and access them from the .NET Framework. I've struggled to be able to make "System.**Data.SqlClient**.SqlConnection" and "System.**Data.Odbc**.OdbcConnection" working. [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739794/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-in-net-standard-2-0-class-library?newreg=5bda126302f141bba9c09eb524a1ec48).

Now I would like to implement "System.**Data.OleDb**.OleDbConnection" but I cannot find the NuGet pack for it.

```
Dim connection As IDbConnection
connection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("")
connection = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("")
connection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("")
```

The Error for the OleDB is:
Error   BC30002 Type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it does not work is OLE is a platform specific technology for windows. You can not use OLE on platforms that are not windows.

For that reason Microsoft did not create a .NET Standard `System.Data.OleDb` NuGet package, you will need to create the Ole connection in a full .net framework library and have it passed in as a `IDbConnection` in to your .NET Standard code.

You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection#applies-to) the list of frameworks that do support Ole Db

**UPDATE:** (copied from a decent answer by [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11708463/peter) that was deleted by a moderator)
MS published a NuGet package for OleDb two weeks ago: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottChamberlain

Comment: @Peter I updated my answer to include your deleted answer's new info about the NuGet package.